# How to include SVG syntax into LaTeX

Tags: svg

Is it possible to include SVG code into LaTex? If it's possible how can I do that ?
Short Example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

I do not have a file with extension .svg, and I have access only to its code.
For result I want to display svg "image".

Comment: Any reason for using the SVG code instead of including a SVG file? After all, a SVG file is just a XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use svg data inside a tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathpazo}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw svg "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz svg triangle]